# error with formula: IF("Close Date" = "26/05/2016", "01/06/2016", "0")

Tags: reporting, formula

I am trying to create a formula in the report so that if the close date is e.g 26/05/2016, return value would be 01/06/2016

formula; `IF("Close Date" = "26/05/2016", "01/06/2016", "0")`

But i keep getting this error :

> Error: Invalid custom summary formula definition: Formula result is
>   data type (Text), incompatible with expected data type (Number)

Answer (score 0):

Your ELSE cannot be 0 (Integer)

IF("CloseDate" = "26/05/2016", "01/06/2016", **"0"**)

It should be CloseDate in the else part too.

```
IF("CloseDate" = "26/05/2016", "01/06/2016", "CloseDate")
```

This implies that if the date is 26/05, it changes to 01/06, ELSE It will be CloseDate itself

Comment: Hi Thanks. however i am trying to do a if on close date field in reports, However i try to use IF(CloseDate= 26/05/2016, 01/06/2016, CloseDate) or IF(Close_Date__c = 26/05/2016, 01/06/2016, Close_Date__c), salesforce keep telling field does not exist, check spelling

Comment: Choose the date field from the dropdown, do not write it down.  Whats the correct field name?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @sfdcFanBoy mentioned and the error message you provided, seems like your formula field has value type set to **Number**. Consider changing it to **Text** and your formula should work fine.